# jQuery dynamic created input sum and subtract on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm working with jquery and need help to calculate the values of input depended on select option inserted dynamically.
i want if select value is debit it will subtract from selected credit value and difference  show in id diff as i inserted more ows all values calculate by debit and credit.

```
<table class="vtable">
    <tr>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="type" id="type">
            <option>-type -</option>
            <option value="debit">debit</option>
            <option value="credit">credit</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="amount"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My fiddle demo is below

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/softfiddle/vNpQQ/)

Thanks

Comment: @David I think OP has posted the demo fiddle link for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/vNpQQ/4/)

Try this

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var input = $(this).parents('td').next('td').find('input:text');
        if (value == 'debit') {
            total -= parseInt(input.val());
        } else if (value == 'credit') {
            total += parseInt(input.val());
        }
        $('#diff').html('Differance:' + total);
    });
```

Hope this helps,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select#type').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() === "debit"){
        //Get the difference between 2 variables and store result in diff
        $("#diff").val(Math.abs(a - b)) 
    }else if($(this).val() === "credit"){
        //perform addition and store value in sum object
        $("#sum").val(x+y)
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this?

```
$('select[name="type"]').change(function()
{
 if($(this).val() === 'credit')
 {
    $("#amount").val() += $('input[type="text"]').val()

 }
 else if($(this).val() === 'debit')
 {
    $("#amount").val() -= $('input[type="text"]').val()
 }
})
```

I use the the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function to trigger the change.
I don't know if this is what you meant, but i hope it helped somehow.

Comment: this is calculation for one as i add more rows not calculate truely please update fiddle Thanks

Answer (score 0):

one issue corrected in `more` button click handlers. see the changes below:

```
$("#more").click(function() {
  $(".vtable tr:last").clone().find("input, select").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({'id': function(_, id) { return id + 1 }});
  }).end().appendTo(".vtable");
});
```

in order to handle the events for dynamically added `select` and `input` text, you can achieve it as follows.

**Note**: `.on()` is used with your table as your are adding rows dynamically with select and input text.

for `select` :

```
$('.vtable').on('change', "select", function (e) {
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    alert(valueSelected);

});
```

for `input` text

```
$('.vtable').on('keyup', "input", function (e) {
    var valueEntered = this.value;
    alert(valueEntered );
});
```